# opencv in Visual Studio 2015, RC2021: expected exponent value, not '1'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I used in opencv in Visual Studio 2015. But when I tried to compile the project, VS told me there was an error:

> RC2021  expected exponent value, not '1'    Img2Ascii   D:\Program Files (x86)\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  244

Here is the wrong code in types_c.h:

```
CV_INLINE double cvRandReal( CvRNG* rng )
{
    return cvRandInt(rng)*2.3283064365386962890625e-10 /* 2^-32 */;
}
```

the main function code:

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    system("pause");
}
```

I've found the error code in msdn, and it said:

> expected exponent value, not 'character'
>   The given character was used as the exponent of a floating-point constant but was not a valid number.

Should I modify the source files of opencv?

Comment: How are you using opencv in your code? Your main function is just including an OpenCV file, but is not using any of the functions, how could it give you any error without calling a function? By the way, `2.3283064365386962890625e-10` is avalid number in c++

Comment: Thanks for your help....I find when I delete all the _#include_ codes in resource.h, it works.....I think it's probably  redefinition error.

Comment: maybe, but it would be weird that it goes without error, and that it affects such a unique named function.